# How to write IF statement in a optimize way for multiple condition for string variable?

Tags: shell

I have a two array as shown in below B and T containing a string which I extracted from a file where B[0] is a output at time T[0],B[1] is a output at time T[1] and so on.**My task is to see at particular time duration T output B can be '0.00' or '1.0' and rest of time it is '0.00' so value of B which I given its just a sample it can be '0.00' or '1.0'**.So is there any better way I can minimize If statement or I can  use a different approach?

```
B:
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.0 0.00 1.0 0.00 1.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
T:
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57

Code:
j=0
for i in ${T[@]}
    do  
        if [ $i == '10' -o $i == '11' -o $i == '12' -o $i == '13' -o $i == '14' -o $i == '15' -o $i == '16' -o $i == '17' -o $i == '18' -o $i =='19' -o $i == '20' -o $i == '51' -o $i == '52' -o $i == '53' -o $i == '54' -o $i == '55'-o $i == '56' -o $i == '57' -o $i == '58' -o $i == '59' -o $i == '60'  ]
        then
            if [ ${B[$j]} == '1.0' -o ${B[$j]} == '0.00' ]
            then
                echo "Passed"
            fi
        else
            if [ ${B[$j]} == '0.00' ]
            then
                echo "Passed"
            else    
                echo "Failed"

            fi
        fi
        j=$(( $j + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: `case $i in 1[0-9]|20|5[1-9]|60)`?

Comment: As an aside, `-o` is marked obsolescent in the POSIX `test` standard (the command also known as `[`), and `==` isn't even specified at all; the standardized string comparison operator is `=`. Search for the `OB` markers in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html. Better to use a `case` statement in your current use case, but when you *do* need a test with multiple branches, use `[ "$i" = 10 ] || [ "$i" = 11 ]`, or the bash/ksh-only replacement `[[ $i = 10 || $i = 11 ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste -d' ' <(printf "%s\n" "${T[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}") \
| sed '
    s/^\(1[0-9]|20|5[1-9]|60\) \(0.00\|1.0\)$/Passed/; t;
    s/^[0-9]\+ 0.00$/Passed/; t;
    s/.*/Failed/;
'
```

1. `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"` prints each array member on a separate line
2. Join the arrays together with a single space as a separator, so you get something like `3 0.00\n6 0.00\n`
3. If the first column is `[0-9]|20|5[1-9]|60` and second is `0.00` or `1.0` then substitute the line for `Passed`
4. If the first column is a number and the second column is 0.00, substitute the line for `Passed`
5. You may see that checking `0.00` part in the first line is reduntand.
6. Everything else is substituted for `Failed`
7. In `sed` the `t` option branches to the end of script, if the previous `s` was successful.

Live version at [tutorialspoints](http://tpcg.io/BNhG7X).

Comment: thanks for very compact solution.I appreciate it.@Kamil Cuk

Comment: s/^[0-9]\+ 0.00$/Passed/; t;  : this line will check only first digit from T and compare D with 0.00 is it?@Kamil Cuk

Comment: `[0-9]\+` matches: - a character from 0 to 9 `[0-9]` - repeated 1 or more times `\+`. If you want to learn regexes, I can recommend playing [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/), you will learn regex in no time. The `^[0-9]\+ 0.00$` checks if the line consists of numbers, followed by space and followed by 0.00. So T must be a number, D must be a 0.00.

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
#!/bin/bash

B=(0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.0 0.00 1.0 0.00 1.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00)
T=(3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57)

Code:
j=0
for i in ${T[@]}; do
        if [[ $i =~ ^(10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60)$ ]]
        then
            if [[ ${B[$j]} == '1.0' || ${B[$j]} == '0.00' ]]
            then
                echo "Passed T=$i B=${B[$j]}"
            fi
        else
            if [[ ${B[$j]} == '0.00' ]]
            then
                echo "Passed T=$i B=${B[$j]}"
            else    
                echo "Failed T=$i B=${B[$j]}"
            fi
        fi
        ((j++))
done
```

Which gives me the output

```
Passed T=3 B=0.00
Passed T=6 B=0.00
Passed T=9 B=0.00
Passed T=12 B=0.00
Passed T=15 B=0.00
Passed T=18 B=0.00
Passed T=21 B=0.00
Passed T=24 B=0.00
Passed T=27 B=0.00
Failed T=30 B=1.0
Passed T=33 B=0.00
Failed T=36 B=1.0
Passed T=39 B=0.00
Failed T=42 B=1.0
Passed T=45 B=0.00
Passed T=48 B=0.00
Passed T=51 B=0.00
Passed T=54 B=0.00
Passed T=57 B=0.00
```

Comment: `=~` is doing an unanchored regex match, so `100` would be matched by `10`. You probably want `^` and `$` markers to anchor (`[[ $i =~ ^(...)$ ]]`).

Comment: (I would also tend to suggest switching from `==` to `=` to avoid reinforcing habits that harm compatibility when applied to `[` in baseline-POSIX environments, but that's a personal/stylistic matter in `[[ ]]`, since `==` is explicitly supported everywhere it is).